# C# How to keep data local, instead of loading data several times from database?

Tags: c#, database, performance, entity-framework, repository

I have a save-function and a refresh-function. Save calls the refresh-function.
Save takes 4'756ms, refresh takes 4'187ms --> save without refresh takes 569ms.
In the refresh-function, it reloads data from the database.
How can I hold my data local, but save changes to the database, so that I haven't to load data from the database several times?

I use the Entity Framework 5 and work with repositories.

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer caching @

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/04/22/tip-14-caching-entity-framework-reference-data.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/435142/Entity-Framework-Second-Level-Caching-with-DbConte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cache like the HttpContext.Current.Cache:

```
internal static class Cache<T>
   {
      public static void Save(IList<T> list, int insertAt, string cacheKey)
      {
         // Cache key per Session
         cacheKey = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID + "~" + cacheKey; 

         if (list != null && list.Count > 0)
         {
            // if list is already there, insert items in list.
            IList<T> cachedList = HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] as IList<T>;
            if (cachedList != null)
            {
               // remove list from cache.
               HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(cacheKey);

               // insert items at position.
               if (insertAt < 0)
               {
                  insertAt = cachedList.Count;
               }
               foreach (T item in list)
               {
                  cachedList.Insert(insertAt, item);
                  insertAt++;
               }
            }
            else
            {
               // check that list is no array, because that cannot be removed.
               cachedList = list.GetType().IsArray ? new List<T>(list) : list;
            }

            // save list in cache for 30 seconds.
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(
                                            cacheKey
                                          , cachedList
                                          , null
                                          , DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30)
                                          , Cache.NoSlidingExpiration
                                            );
         }
      }

      public static void Save(IList<T> list, string cacheKey)
      {
         Save(list, -1, cacheKey);
      }
      public static void Save(IList<T> list, int insertAt)
      {
         Save(list, insertAt, typeof(T).Name);
      }

      public static int Remove(T item, string cacheKey)
      {
         // index of removed item.
         int removedIndex = -1;
         // cache key per Session
         cacheKey = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID + "~" + cacheKey; 

         if (item != null)
         {
            // remove from  cache.
            IList<T> cachedList = HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] as IList<T>;
            if (cachedList != null)
            {
               // remove list from cache.
               HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(cacheKey);

               // remove item from cached list..
               removedIndex = cachedList.IndexOf(item);
               cachedList.Remove(item);

               // insert list for 30 sec.
               HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(
                                               cacheKey
                                             , cachedList
                                             , null
                                             , DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30)
                                             , Cache.NoSlidingExpiration
                                               );
            }
         }
         return removedIndex;
      }

      public static int Remove(T item)
      {
         return Remove(item, typeof(T).Name);
      }

      public static void Clear(string cacheKey)
      {
         // cache Key per Session
         cacheKey = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID + "~" + cacheKey;

         HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(cacheKey);
      }

      public static void Clear()
      {
         Clear(typeof(T).Name);
      }

}
```